# Use numbers with commas in Jekyll data

Tags: jekyll

If I've got some data like this:
size: 99999

It outputs like so:

```
<div>99999</div>
```

How can I add commas so the whole project will output numbers like this

```
<div>99,999</div>
```

I know I can make it a string '99,999' but it would be easier so I can manage the whole project.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a liquid filter like this one: https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/567#issuecomment-102047019

Comment: Thanks mate, will give it a shot!